# Looping of constructor this.state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, state

I would like to declare many variables into the `state`. How to use dynamic method to do that?

For example:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state =
    {
     test1: this.props.navigation.state.params.rowData.test1,
     test2: this.props.navigation.state.params.rowData.test2,
      .........
     test50: this.props.navigation.state.params.rowData.test50
    }
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you attempting to do this and what lead your data to be structured in that manner?

Comment: Why not just use an array?

Comment: I would like to create an edit information page and create many inputtext with dynamic method, when the input changed, it needs to update the state variable

Answer (score 3):

You can use `for loop` for that. For example:

```
for(let i = 0; i < 50; i++){
  this.setState({ [i]: this.props.navigation.state.params.rowData.[i] })
}
```

If you want to do it exactly how in your example, you must `push` all your tests in the `object`, and in the `setState` just set this object.

Something like this:

```
var obj = {};
for(let i = 0; i < 50; i++){
  obj[test+i] = test+i;
}
this.setState({test: [ ...this.state.test, obj]});
```

Comment: for(let i = 0; i < 50; i++){
  this.setState({ test[i]: this.props.navigation.state.params.rowData.[i] })
}

Comment: that's an example, in this case, create an empty array in your state and name it `test`. See if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just spread them in?

```
this.state = { ...this.props.navigation.state.params.rowData }
```

Comment: what is the meaning of ... ?

Comment: @HowardLam it's a "Object Spread" operator. The ES6 syntax for `Object.assign()` . For more information you can read this article: https://thecodebarbarian.com/object-assign-vs-object-spread.html

Comment: Thanks. it works now. but there is one more questions.....how can I use looping for set state petty+i?? any syntax i can use?    <TextInput
         onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({petty+i:text})}
          value={eval("this.state.petty"+i)}
   />

Comment: @HowardLam You keep using eval. As I said in a previous comment this is completely unnecessary by using bracket Boston for your property access. You may want to take a step back--there's a few things going here that make me think some tutorials on basic JS, React, and data structures will save you significant time and headaches.